# UITextField Validation visual feedback

Tags: iphone, validation, uitextfield

i have a uiTextField that i am validating input on, when i have invalid input what are some appropriate ways to show that the input is invalid? is there any built in mechanism for showing invalid input states?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty easy to add an 'warning' image to the left-hand side of a UITextField to indicate that the field needs a value.

Try this:

```
UITextField* field = .... your text field ...

if ( fails_validation ) {
  field.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
  UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"];
  imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  field.leftView = imageView;
} else {
  field.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
  field.leftView = nil;
}
```

Comment: if you prefer to have it on the right, use field.rightView instead of field.leftView.

Answer (score 6):

The best two options I've found so far are [TextFieldValidator](https://dhawaldawar.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/uitextfield-validation-ios/) and [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator). With the caveat that I have only used the former, here's my take on each.

**[TextFieldValidator](https://dhawaldawar.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/uitextfield-validation-ios/)**

- ↑ Simple (just one class!)
- ↑ Offers default UI with additional customization possible
- ↑ Handles multiple validations on a single field
- ↓ Doesn't handle text *views*
- ↓ Slightly awkward name…`ValidatedTextField`, for example, would be more accurate :)

**[US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator)**

- ↑ Handles text fields *and* text views
- ↑ Importable as a framework, including CocoaPods support
- ↑ Handles multiple validations on a single field
- ↓ No default UI

If you just need something implemented quickly, TextFieldValidator may be all you need. If you *must* have validated UIText*Views*, US2FormValidator is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Managing Overlay Views* section in UITextField docs

Comment: Heres's a link for this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html

Answer (score 0):

Put a check mark to the right of the UITextField when correct, Else put an X to the right of it. to make it look smooth: fade it using an animation