# display checkmark on UITextField righthand side

Tags: uitextfield, checkmark

I am trying to display checkmark on UITextField righthandside on tapGesture.
Could you please help me to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField Validation visual feedback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906799/uitextfield-validation-visual-feedback)

Comment: Thanks, By this i am able to achieve.

Comment: I have a UITextField also for customCell for UITableView. On TapGesture of UITextField, I need to display checkmark on right side of UITableViewCell. I am able to achieve this, when I am setting textfield property enabled=NO. But I have to keep enable property ON.

Comment: You must include what you've tried in your question body. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for what you exactly looking for

http://dhawaldawar.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/uitextfield-validation-ios/

I have created inherited class of UITextField for validating input effectively, you just need to give regex string in sequence for validation on a particular field and other things like show error on right side and showing popup with a message that we provided at the time of assigning regex will handle by class itself.

I'm damm sure it will save your lot of work...